# In SSRS : How to disable Date parameter based on value of other Parameter

Tags: reporting-services

How I can control Parameter based on values in another parameter?

I have 3 fields in my report:

```
Include All Dates
Start date
End Date
```

If user enter 'No' in `Include All Dates` parameter then `Start date` and `End Date` parameter should be editable otherwise it should be grayed.

My parameters look like this:

[image: Parameters]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I hope you have already checked [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691210/ssrs-grey-out-parameter-based-on-result-from-other-parameter)

If that doesn't help then please make simple screen and pass parameters to Report it would be great if you do like this way. As Even I had the same problem but I could not make it possible. While passing parameters from that screen, it must be hide from report parameter properties.

*Let me know, if you need more help. I will definitely help you in this issue*

Comment: Yes I tried that but when i follow the steps I created a dataset IncludeData and Try to link My Startdate and end date with the dataset it gives me error that it cannot find the Includedate parameter.I am not sure what mistake I am doing.

Comment: show me the code I will help you to fix the problem.

Comment: I added a dataset Includedata ,Here I wrote a query  IF @Includedate = 'Yes' SELECT        NULL AS Date ELSE    SELECT        cast('1/1/2012' AS datetime) as Date .I try to link it with startdate and enddate default value but it gives me error

Comment: When I run the report i get an error:The value expression for the query parameter '@includedate refer to an non existing parameter

Comment: Possibly some parameter casing issue, it must be the same. also please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252588/ssrs-2008-error-message-saying-my-parameter-doesnt-exist-but-it-clearly-does

Comment: It is working now but it is not grayed when I select @IncludeDate ="yes"

Comment: please change it from  `@IncludeDate` ="yes" to  `@IncludeDate` =yes - I mean in parameters available values it should be simply Yes - No and in default values it should be No Or Yes. then try

Comment: I did that , now when i preview the report When i Select "Yes" my startdate and enndate get selected as default value and when i select "no" it gives me calender control to choose the date , but when i click to ViewReport button automatically values disappear

Comment: it can be caching issue, can u pls delete cache and then try. Also I would like to discuss more with you on this topic but as you don't have 25 reputation I cannot discuss so sorry for that

Comment: Every time I select a value and click on view report values disapear and it gives me error,Please enter the value for the parameter.I am running this in VisulaStudio I restarted it again but it no luck.

Comment: check report parameter properties and go to advanced. tick never refresh to check it starts working or not.

Comment: No I selected option 'never Refresh' but still when I select dates range and click on view report ,value disappear

Comment: now I need to check whole scenario very carefully. as it is just minor issue but not easily find.